# AWS ECS Fargate service task unable to access AWS Rekognition service - 504 Gateway Timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs, amazon-rekognition

I have setup an ECS Fargate service. Task is setup with a task role. Also, I have a VPC endpoint setup for the Rekognition service. However, I am getting a 504 Gateway timeout when calling the Rekognition service API.

Please note that I am able to make a call to the S3 buckets with a similar setup.

What am I missing when connecting to the Rekognition API?

Task Role Policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "rekognition:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Task Role Trust Relations:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

Service Security Group Inbound/Outbound Rules:
[image]

Subnets: ECS Services are running in a private subnet.

Comment: Are the Lambda an ECS tasks running in the exact same VPC subnet? Is the Lambda even running in the VPC at all? Does the ECS task have public IP assigned?

Comment: You've changed Lambda to 'similar setup' - what setup is that? That will help debug the issue.

Comment: @MarkB - Just updated my answer. Lambdas are not running in the VPC so removed it from my answer. ECS tasks doesn't have a public IP and they are running in a private subnet.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary - 'Similar Setup' - I am referring to the ECS task role, VPC endpoint, ECS service security groups. Service that is connecting to S3 has a task role attached to S3FullAccess whereas service that is connecting to Rekognition API has  RekognitionFullAccess policy attached.

Comment: Does the private subnet have a route to a NAT Gateway? If not, do you have a Recognition endpoint configured in the VPC? The error you are getting is not related to permissions, so we need to see all your network configuration settings.

Comment: @MarkB thanks for the tip. While rechecking the network configuration I observed that I didn't enabled the Private DNS Name. Once turned it on I am able to make the calls to the Rekognition APIs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon rechecking my network configurations, I realized I had not enabled the `Private DNS names` flag preventing me from using the Rekognition API. Thanks to @MarkB for the help.

To summarize:

1. ECS Fargate service's task has a **Task Role**, which allows access to the Rekognition Service. In my case, I attached the `AmazonRekognitionFullAccess` policy to the Task Role.
2. ECS Service's security group has the required Inbound/Outbound rules.
3. VPC Endpoint -> If the services are in a private subnet and you want to make a private call -> Add a VPN Endpoint with the service name `com.amazonaws.us-west-2.rekognition`. Also, enable the Private DNS names.
4. VPC Endpoints security group has the required Inbound/Outbound rules. And VPC Endpoint Policy is set up as needed.